# Python: Excel to data frame : removing top rows and columns that doesnt contain 'right' data

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

I got a rather very basic excel to Pandas issue which I am unable to get around. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
[Source file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hmxzjj61meov2n4v0pln1/test_data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=qw134ssk6ux0in76xljj6pqc0)

I got some data in an excel like below(apologies for pasting a picture and not Table):

[image]

Columns A,B,C are not required. I need the highlighted data to be read/moved into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: pass the column names to `read_excel`: ``pd.read_excel(filename, usecols="D:G")``

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't know the columns name. see this error.

    `Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: {missing}

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['D:G']`

Comment: and the actual data is the same as what you shared? what of ``pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])`` ?

Comment: Yes, I am testing on the same data I shared in the above snapshot.

Comment: if you can, kindly share the source file. also, what version of Pandas are you on?

Comment: Pandas 1.2.4
apologies for my ignorance, but how do I share the source file here?

Comment: you can share with google drive or some other sharing service you are comfy with. As long as your data does not contain any information you would not like to share

Comment: no need to share the file, I think the answer below should work for you

Comment: Here is the link to source file
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hmxzjj61meov2n4v0pln1/test_data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=qw134ssk6ux0in76xljj6pqc0)

Comment: ``pd.read_excel('test_data.xlsx', usecols = "D:G", skiprows=7); df = df.set_axis(df.iloc[0], axis=1).drop(0)`` using the file shared. pandas version I am using is 1.3.1. Again, the answer offered below should work fine; I think you should pick that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_excel('Miscel.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',skiprows=8, usecols=[3,4,5,6])
df

    Date        Customers   Location    Sales
0   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12
1   2021-10-03  B           NSW         10
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33
```

If your data is small, you can also read in and then drop the Nan.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Miscel.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',skiprows=8).dropna(how='all',axis=1)
```

Comment: @sammywemmy it was mentioned in the question.

Comment: @sammywemmy "I got a rather very basic ***excel*** to Pandas issue". still there !

Comment: @sammywemmy it wasnt sheet2, but the solution works :)